# Spring Cloud Sleuth and Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis - How to propagate trace IDs?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth

Do Spring Cloud Sleuth tracing headers get injected into Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis messages like they do for RabbitMq and Kafka as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.0.1/reference/htmlsingle/#sleuth-messaging-spring-rabbitmq-integration)? We have a REST controller that, after processing a POST request but right before sending the response to the client, sends an Avro message to Kinesis that summarizes the transaction using Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis. I want to ensure that the trace id started in the REST controller is propagated to the Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis message, and I am unsure of how to configure this or whether it's even supported by the framework. When I log the message and headers in the microservice that processes this Avro message, I see a different trace ID (and, of course, span ID). Propagation does not appear to be configured and/or working properly across this REST controller to Kinesis message context.

We are currently using Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR10`, Spring Boot `2.3.9.RELEASE`, and Spring Cloud Kinesis `2.0.1.RELEASE`.

As a side note, I have tried upgrading Spring Cloud Kinesis to `2.0.2.RELEASE`, `2.0.3.RELEASE`, and `2.0.4.RELEASE` but encounter errors with each of these binder upgrades. I'm not certain what version combinations of Spring Cloud, Spring Boot, and Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis work with each other.

**Example code**

```
@PostMapping(
      value = "/accountEntry",
      consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},
      produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
  public ResponseEntity<Confirmation> createAccountEntry(
      @RequestBody final AccountEntry accountEntry,
      final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final AccountEntryEvent accountEntryEvent =
        new AccountEntryEvent(convertToAvro(accountEntry), AccountEntryEventType.CREATE_ACCOUNT_ENTRY);
    accountEntryChannels
        .accountEntryRequest()
        .send(
            MessageBuilder.withPayload(accountEntryEvent)
                .build());
    final Confirmation confirmation = buildConfirmation();
    final EntityModel<Confirmation> confirmationEntityModel =
        new EntityModel<>(confirmation);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(confirmationEntityModel, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}

// with a brave.Tracer instance autowired, I'm able to obtain the trace id as follows
protected String getTraceId() {
  return tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString();
}
  
@Component
public interface AccountEntryChannels {
  @Output("account-entry-request")
  SubscribableChannel accountEntryRequest();
  ...
}
```

Comment: How do you do "Rest to Kinesis"? Do you really use a Binder to produce message from your custom sink? You need to be sure that binder is configured for the `HeaderMode.embeddedHeaders` because there is no headers abstraction in Kinesis at all...

Comment: ```headerMode``` is set to ```embeddedHeaders``` by default, right? We are not explicitly setting it. So, to answer your first question, what I'm saying is that within my REST controller I write a message to the message channel, and I want these trace and span ids to propagate to my Kinesis message. So, I'm not producing messages from a sink, I'm sending messages as a step in my REST controller. So, if by default we're using ```embeddedHeaders```, then is there a way to propagate these to my Kinesis message?

Comment: Still not clear: do you use Kinesis binder on the producer side or just channel adapter subscribed to the mentioned channel?

Comment: I use the Kinesis binder on the producer side.

Comment: Ok. Show , please, how you send a message to that channel . Are you sure that you carry tracing headers from the controller method?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have added example code to my original post. This REST controller's purpose is to accept JSON data POSTed from a REST client, convert it to Avro, send that Avro data as a message over Kinesis, and finally return a confirmation to the client.

Comment: So, I see you do `.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(accountEntryEvent).build());`. And where are those tracing headers you would like to propagate?

Comment: I simply want the Spring Cloud Sleuth trace id to propagate to my Kinesis message so that on the consumer side, when I log messages the same trace id is logged and, of course, a new and different span would be logged on the consumer side. I have added a method to my original post showing how today on the producer side I can get the trace id programatically.

Comment: @ArtemBilan based on my last comment, is there any way to do this?

Comment: The `MessageBuilder` has a `setHeader()` API. So, just add that `getTraceId()` into header of the message you send! Probably there must be some kind of `ChannelInterceptor` to propagate such an info from the `ThreadLocal` into message headers, but I don't know details what you have so far in your environment. Probably you need to configure that interceptor explicitly or so...

Answer (score 0):

If you use it through the `StreamBinder` or `MessageChannel`, it should work, if you use it in the functional way (`Supplier`+`BlockingQueue`) it should not, the functional way is not supported.